# search the string and the number in a table

Tags: php, mysql, search

I have some set of problem in search. I have a table classDetails and I have className, classNumber, classSubject. Now in class name there will be some set of data like. computer science, mec, electrical, etc.. in class subject the data will be like. IT,EEE,MEC and etc... in class number the data will be like. 233, 3213, 12,etc.. in this if user search the table they used to search like it 233, or eee 12, etc.. i have tried many options like

```
SELECT * FROM classes_detail 
WHERE classDeleted = 0 AND 
( 
   LOWER(classCollege) LIKE "%'.  trim($searchTxt). '%"  OR 
   classNumber LIKE "%'.  trim($searchTxt). '%" OR 
   CONCAT( classNumber , LOWER(classCollege) ) LIKE "%'.  trim($searchTxt). '%" 
)
```

can any one find me a best search term for this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try

```
SELECT * FROM classes_detail
WHERE classDeleted = 0 
  AND LOWER(CONCAT_WS(' ',subject,class_num)) = LOWER(your_param)
```

or (to search some more free text)

```
SELECT * FROM classes_detail
WHERE classDeleted = 0 
  AND (LOWER(CONCAT_WS(' ', subject, class_num)) = LOWER(your_param)
   OR LOWER(subject) = LOWER(your_param)
   OR LOWER(class_num) = LOWER(your_param))
```

Comment: That would only pick up results where the user searched on terms in the correct order and on the whole string. For example, for the course "EEE 12", just searching on "12" or just "EEE" wouldn't find that result.

Comment: It's better but I still think it's best to direct the OP to other free-text search options out there, if he actually needs a free-text search. It may be that he/his users don't need a full free-text search.

Answer (score 0):

Free text searching is a huge topic (just ask Google!) and there a whole host of ways you might approach this. If your data is well-structured, fairly static and relatively small (i.e. the class subject only has 5-10 options like IT,EEE,MEC that rarely change), you might want to refine your search options for users so they have to explicitly select which of those they are looking for.

Alternatively, you might want to investigate [MySQL's full-text searching options](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html). Or you might even want to step up and look at a standalone solution like [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) (this is just one option, there are loads more like it).

There isn't one size fits all; it all depends on how your data is structured and what your users are going to want.